# CMake to create a exe and lib with (prepackaged headers and dlls)

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
    project(ImageProc)

    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

    find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
    find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

    add_definitions( -fPIC -Wall -O3)
    include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    #link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}) Dont think neccesary..
    add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

    add_executable (ImageProc svm.cpp ImageProc.cpp testImageProc.cpp)
    target_link_libraries (ImageProc ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
    add_library(ImageProcLib STATIC svm.cpp ImageProc.cpp)
    target_link_libraries (ImageProcLib ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Currently, I run this and open with VS C++ and generate an exe and lib.
The exe runs on my machine.

Current limitations:
When I pass the exe to my friend, he cant run it on his machine as he gets hit by host of missing dlls.
When I use the lib files, to create a new project in VS C++, there is a fatal error in not finding a header file.
I know, I can manually add all the dlls and or package all the header and library files for the lib. But it is definitely cumbersome and ugly also.

Question:
Does CMake offer a way, so that when compiling into

1. An exe (it will automatically find all the necessary dlls into bin directory)
2. Into a lib (it will automatically source out all the header files and also the neccesary library for the linking part into the lib directory)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Packaging applications for deployment has always been a tough task.

Answer (score 0):

Preparing your package for deployment on other development environment can still be a tough task. You will  need to setup your own interfaces/API correctly and will need to deal with cross-dll issues, different runtimes, etc.

However, there are a few tools from CMake at your disposal:

- Check out the [Install](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:install) and [Export](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:export). You can use it to specify (in your CMakeLists.txt) which files are necessary for deployment. This way, you can mark which header-files, but also which targets (libs and exes) should be deployed.
- Also take a look at CPack in combination with NSIS, which can be used to build NSIS installers of your project.
- Together with the [InstallRequiredSystemLibraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module:InstallRequiredSystemLibraries) and [BundleUtilities](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module:BundleUtilities) you can then prepare an `install` or `package` target. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970845/cmake-how-to-determine-all-the-dll-so-files-that-are-need-for-an-executable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022993/cmake-build-cross-platform-distribution) question demonstrating how third-party dlls can be added to such a deployment package.
- [InstallRequiredSystemLibraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module:InstallRequiredSystemLibraries) is very useful for appending vcredist to your own package installer, which you will surely need if you are installing your project on a non-development pc.