# How to copy linked and mingw libs to output dir of executable?

Tags: cmake, deployment

I'm new in CMake.
Could someone please describe to me what I should write in my CMakeLists.txt to copy dependencies to the output directory of the executable file?

So, I have a CMake project:

```js
# top-level CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(CoolLib VERSION 0.0.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_subdirectory(mylib)
add_subdirectory(mytestconsole)

install(TARGETS mnconsole mnlib
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin           COMPONENT Runtime
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib           COMPONENT Runtime
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/myproject COMPONENT Development)

# mylib/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(mylib VERSION 0.0.1)
add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp mylib.h)
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# mytestconsole/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(mytestconsole VERSION 0.0.1)
add_executable(mytestconsole main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mytestconsole LINK_PUBLIC mylib)
target_include_directories(mytestconsole PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib)
```

As you can see, I've added an `install()` command, but this isn't exactly what I want.
As far as I understand, the `install()` command will copy my program to the `Program Files` directory in Windows.

**GOAL:**
I want to copy the mingw libraries (e.g. `libgcc_s_seh-1`, `libstdc++-6`, `libwinpthread-1`, etc.) and `mylib` to the output directory of the `mytestconsole.exe` file.

PS: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36164501/8739685) answer, but `GetPrerequesites` is deprecated. And I didn't understand how to use it.

I tried to do this:

```js
add_custom_command(
        TARGET mnconsole POST_BUILD
        COMMAND LIST_PREREQUISITES($<TARGET_FILE:mnconsole>)
        VERBATIM)
```

But got an error:

```
D:\Programs\JetBrains\CLion\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe --build D:\Projects\MethaneNumber\_builds\debug --target mnconsole -j 9
[1/1] Linking CXX executable mnconsole\mnconsole.exe
FAILED: mnconsole/mnconsole.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\Programs\mingw64\12.2.0\x64\posix-seh\bin\c++.exe -g  mnconsole/CMakeFiles/mnconsole.dir/main.cpp.obj -o mnconsole\mnconsole.exe -Wl,--out-implib,mnconsole\libmnconsole.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  mnlib/libmnlib.a  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cmd.exe /C "cd /D D:\Projects\MethaneNumber\_builds\debug\mnconsole && LIST_PREREQUISITES ( D:/Projects/MethaneNumber/_builds/debug/mnconsole/mnconsole.exe )""
"LIST_PREREQUISITES" is ­not recognized as an internal command.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

PS2: It should work like `windeployqt.exe` with Qt, but I'm not using Qt in this project right now.